# how connect, open, add to a sqlite Database on a system using c/ Objective C and FTP/SSH from another system

Tags: c, xcode, sqlite, ssh, ftp

I have a SQLite Database "a.db" on a Mac of which I have all FTP and SSH details. I have to append some data from my mac to 'a.db'. So far I have done it for same system only, using  libsqlite3.dylib on Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

It can use ftp pass db data to server, use ssh command add sqlite data to sqlite server.

Comment: can you provide some example, links because i am new to ssh and ftp.